# M1 Mac Problem Installing Homebrew hangs at installing XCode

Tags: xcode, installation, homebrew

I need to install homebrew to install different software packages in my computer.
However, I first tried using homebrew and got

> zsh: command not found: brew

I then tried fixing this issue following different methods such as adding `opt/homebrew/bin/` to the PATH, adding export `PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin/"`
to my `~/.zshrc` file but nothing worked. One of the methods required me to errase the folder `/opt/homebrew` and then install homebrew via `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` (specified in brew.sh website). This hangs during the installation. This is the output shown in my command line

```
~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/etc
/opt/homebrew/include
/opt/homebrew/lib
/opt/homebrew/sbin
/opt/homebrew/share
/opt/homebrew/var
/opt/homebrew/opt
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
/opt/homebrew/var/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked
/opt/homebrew/Cellar
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom
/opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> The Xcode Command Line Tools will be installed.

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/install -d -o root -g wheel -m 0755 /opt/homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod ug=rwx /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod go-w /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown alchandeck /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R alchandeck:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Searching online for the Command Line Tools
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
```

We can see the installation hangs when trying to install XCode Command Line Tools. So, I then tried to install XCode different ways but got no luck either. Please help me figure out how to install homebrew so I can start developing in my computer! Thanks!

Blockquote

Edit:
After a while of waiting, the Xcode installation timed out (not surprised) and showed me this:

> Timed out while loading data from the Apple Software Update server.
> ==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/rm -f /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
> Password:
> ==> Installing the Command Line Tools (expect a GUI popup):
> ==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install
> xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
> Press any key when the installation has completed.

Answer (score -2):

I was finally able to solve it by following this post https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/131

I basically downloaded the version of Command Line Tools that was compatible with my macOS version and then proceed as normal with my brew install command provided in brew.sh

The only caveat is that when I ran the brew install command, I was prompted with a message saying I had not agreed with the Terms and Conditions of the Command Line Tools, which was fairly easy to do any ways. After agreeing, I tried running the brew install command again and was able to install it.